# React-NextJs not rendering a list with items from a fake api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Please help, I have a nextJS app that is not rendering a list with items from an array of objects called productList. I'm trying to render the productList starting on line 26 in the following code:

[image: this is what I get from that console.log]

In addition I've verified that the productList array exists and is properly composed in a console.log statement on line 16.  Here is what appears in the console:

[image: This is my code]

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being voted down.  It's clear, it's useful, and while it may not exhibit very much research effort, beginning react users often get hung up on these sort of iteration challenges.  Maybe people are objecting to the code being represented in an image.  Since that may be the case try cutting and pasting the actual code into your question in lieu of the image.

Comment: Another strategy you might use to get this question opened up again is to provide a code snippet that zeros in on the problem with more focus.  Since the console reveals that the problem is not in your fetch, simply create a component, declare the productList variable and load it with the array of objects, and then show the code that is attempting to render it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched, copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: In addition, your screenshot uses programming ligatures, e.g. showing `⇒` instead of `=>`. For users who aren't using ligatures, this is very hard to read. Posting text as _text_ avoids this problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the kindly answers, I'm new here and I'm not used to using this platform, I will ensure to not repeating this mistake again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the callback you are defining inside the map, currently you are defining the body of that callback using curly braces, in order to make your code works you should add a return statement, or better you could replace the curly braces by parenthesis and it should work, below you can find both solutions:

```
{productList.map(product => (
  <ul>
    <li key={product.id}>{product.name}</li>
  </ul>
))}
```

or

```
{productList.map(product => {
  return (<ul>
    <li key={product.id}>{product.name}</li>
  </ul>);
})}
```

Comment: This answer is correct.  Here's a stackblitz snippet that  iterates thru and renders a very similar array of objects:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-basket55